# Ansible: is it possible to feed a remote task with local files (avoid first uploading the file)

Tags: ansible

Suppose I have this Ansible task :

```
  - name: Run ETL 2
    shell: psql -U {{dbuser}} -d {{dbname}} -f /tmp/data-cleansing2.sql
    sudo_user: postgres
```

I have many of them like these, and I first have to upload the file

```
  - name: Upload ETL script 
    copy: src=../data-cleansing2.sql /tmp/data-cleansing2.sql
```

It would be nice if there was a way to tell ansible that it must first upload the file, ex:

```
  - name: Run ETL 2
    shell: psql -U {{dbuser}} -d {{dbname}} -f {{/abc/xyz.sql | upload_file}}
    sudo_user: postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the `script` module. The module runs a local script on a remote node after transferring it.

The `script` module takes the script name followed by a list of space-delimited arguments. The local script at path will be transferred to the remote node and then executed. The given script will be processed through the shell environment on the remote node.

Using this module, however, you'd have to first add your calls to psql to the script files. [See here for more info](http://docs.ansible.com/script_module.html).